# Issue with Parameter Assignment in OpenModelica: Some Parameters Not Assigning Correctly

Tags: parameter-passing, openmodelica

I am trying to create a package in OpenModelica containing several building models, and I am using some of the models from Buildings library within my models.
I want to **define a parameter list** for one of my models (e.g., modelOne) **and directly assign them to the parameters of other models** that I used in my model (e.g., Buildings.ThermalZones.ReducedOrder.RC.OneElement thermalZone). By doing that, I can reuse my model also within another model (e.g., modelTwo).

Here is an example:

model modelOne

```
model modelOne
 parameter Integer nOrientations(min=1)=5;
 parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Volume VAir=3852;
 parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Area AWin[nOrientations]
   ={90.72, 30.24, 90.72, 30.24, 0};
 parameter Modelica.Units.SI.CoefficientOfHeatTransfer hConIn=2.7;
 parameter Modelica.Units.SI.TransmissionCoefficient gWin=0.6;
 Buildings.ThermalZones.ReducedOrder.RC.OneElement thermalZone(
   nOrientations=nOrientations, 
   VAir=VAir, 
   AWin=AWin, 
   hConExt=hConIn, 
   hConWin=hConIn, 
   gWin=gWin);
 .
 .
 .
equation
 .
 .
 .
end modelOne;

model modelTwo
 modelOne newModel(
   nOrientations=2, 
   VAir=52.5, 
   AWin={7, 7}, 
   hConIn=4.2, 
   gWin=1.0);
 .
 .
 .
equation
 .
 .
 .
end modelTwo;
```

However, **this way of directly assigning a parameter to another parameter only works for some of them**.
For instance, in the above-mentioned example, it works for nOrientations, VAir, and AWin. For hConIn and gWin, this is what I get:

```
getParameters(["thermalZone.hConIn", "thermalZone.gWin"]);
['None', 'None]
```

I would appreciate it if someone can help me figure out:

- **Why is this happening?**
- **How can I fix this?**
- **Is there any other method than directly assigning one parameter to another?**

Best regards,
Farnaz

Comment: It is unclear what are you trying to do. Are you using scripting api or OMPython or what?

Comment: I made the models and defined parameters in OpenModelica (the example is the text view of OpenModelica), and then tried to get the parameters (getParameters(["thermalZone.hConIn", "thermalZone.gWin"])) using OMPython.